# How to identify a piece of data in an SQLite database's column?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This is my first time setting up an SQLite DataBase, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to control the cursor. Let's say my column names are (author,yearPublished, title) in that order. And lets say I already saved a few entries into the data base like:

1. Bob, 2007, "The Builder"
2. Jack, 2003, "The Headless Horseman"
3. Andy, 2012, "The Mysterious Legend"

So for each book title there is a button with the books name on it(For example, "The Builder" would be on a button the user created). The user can then click on this button, go to another activity page, and have information for this book already put in. For example, it's almost like a library where a new book comes in called "Green Eggs and Ham" by Dr.Seuss, published:1960. The user goes through the other parts of my app, entering the information for this book, thus saving the data into the SQLite database as an entry and creating a button with "Green Eggs and Ham" on it. And when the user clicks on this button, it leads to a page with information:

Author:  Dr.Seuss/
Published: 1960/
Title:  Green Eggs and Ham

My question is, how can I identify a title in my database like "Green Eggs and Ham" and then retrieve all the other information that came with it.

My thoughts on how I want it to work:

```
 cursor=DataBase.column("title").StringWithId("GreenEggsAndHam").getRowInformation();
 String title=cursor.get("title");
 int published=cursor.get("yearPublished");
 String author=cursor.get("author")
```

But obviously this isn't valid syntax.

My DataBase Code:

```
 public class DataHandler {
public static final String PRIORITY="priority";
public static final String LEASTHOURS="leastHours";
public static final String LEASTMINUTES="leastMinutes";
public static final String EXACTHOURS="exactHours";
public static final String EXACTMINUTES="exactMinutes";
public static final String SETHOURS="setHours";
public static final String SETMINUTES="setMinutes";
public static final String SETAMPM="setAmPm";
public static final String ACTIVITYNAME="activityName";
public static final String TABLE_NAME="mytable";
public static final String DATA_BASE_NAME="mydatabase";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
public static final String TABLE_CREATE="create table mytable(name text not null,email text not null);";

DataBaseHelper dbhelper;
Context ctx;
SQLiteDatabase db;
public DataHandler(Context ctx)
{
    this.ctx=ctx;
    dbhelper=new DataBaseHelper(ctx);
}

private static class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public DataBaseHelper(Context ctx){

        super(ctx,DATA_BASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        try{
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        }
        catch(RuntimeException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable");
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public DataHandler open()
{
    db=dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close()
{
    dbhelper.close();
}

public long insertData(int priority, int leastHours,int leastMinutes,int exactHours,
        int exactMinutes,int setHours ,int setMinutes,String setAmPm,String activityName)
{
    ContentValues content=new ContentValues();
    content.put(PRIORITY, priority);
    content.put(LEASTHOURS, leastHours);
    content.put(LEASTMINUTES, leastMinutes);
    content.put(EXACTHOURS, exactHours);
    content.put(EXACTMINUTES, exactMinutes);
    content.put(SETHOURS, setHours);
    content.put(SETMINUTES, setMinutes);
    content.put(SETAMPM, setAmPm);
    content.put(ACTIVITYNAME, activityName);
    return db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, content);
}

public Cursor returnData()
{
    return db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{PRIORITY,LEASTHOURS,LEASTMINUTES,
            EXACTHOURS,EXACTMINUTES,SETHOURS,SETMINUTES,SETAMPM,ACTIVITYNAME},
            null, null, null, null,null);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SQLiteDatabase#query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

```
public Cursor getDetailsForBook(String title) {
    return db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {"title", "yearPublished","author"}, 
                    "title like " + "'%" + title +"%'", null, null, null, null);
}
```

and then read details as :

```
Cursor cursor = dbhandler.getDetailsForBook("Green Eggs and Ham");
String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title"));
int published = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("yearPublished"));
String author = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("author"));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor a = db.rawQuery ("SELECT * FROM MyTable" , null);
            a.moveToFirst();

String title = a.getString(a.getColumnIndex("title"));
int published =a.getInt(a.getColumnIndex("yearPublished"));
String author =a.getString(a.getColumnIndex("author"));
a.close();
```

Comment: So, what if I wanted to get the third entry, considering that there may be like 2 other books in front of the one i want, or does the rawQuery do that?

Comment: i think yes, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some checks and improving the search efficiency

db extends the SQLiteDatabase class

```
String title = null;
int published=0;
String author = null;
Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM people WHERE title = ?", new String[] {"Green Eggs and Ham"});
if(cur.getCount() > 0){
    title = cur.getString(a.getColumnIndex("title"));
    published =cur.getInt(a.getColumnIndex("yearPublished"));
    author =cur.getString(a.getColumnIndex("author"));
    cur.close();
    }
```

Comment: After FROM comes the table's name? and I understand the cur!=null, but what's the cur.getCount()>0 for?